# Poynting of EM field and group velocity

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Could anyone please show me mathematically how the poynting vector of an EM field is always parallel to its group velocity? I do understand the physical reason why it has to be the case, but showing that it is true for all continuous media is tricky to me.

Thank you.